# Cucumber: undefined step, although step should be defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have created the step:

```
    Given /^the feed "([^"]*)" has an item "([^"]*)" published at "([^"]*)"$/ do |feed_name, feed_item_title, published_at|
  feed = Feed.find_by_name(feed_name)
  FeedItem.make(:feed => feed, :title => feed_item_title, :published_at => published_at)
end
```

And I run the cucumber test with:

```
Scenario: feed items should be sorted by date
    Given I am signed into an account called "GT" as a customer
    And there is a social feed called "Twitter" for the account "GT"
    And the feed Twitter has an item Majbrasa published at "2010-05-01"
    --- more follows
```

Cucumber states:

```
7 steps (4 skipped, 1 undefined, 2 passed)
You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given /^the feed Twitter has an item Majbrasa published at "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

I just can't see what's wrong with my step. What is it that I'm missing?
Thanks in advance, Emil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your step you need the  " " around Twitter so use it same about Majbrasa

```
Scenario: feed items should be sorted by date
    Given I am signed into an account called "GT" as a customer
    And there is a social feed called "Twitter" for the account "GT"
    And the feed "Twitter" has an item "Majbrasa" published at "2010-05-01"
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: http://rubular.com/ is a great resource to assist with troubleshooting your step definitions matching your steps.