# Cucumber: Undefined step although the step is defined

Tags: ruby, cucumber, selenium-webdriver, gherkin

**I have this step implementation**

Given /^entity URI "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1|
  @entityUri = arg1
end

**I copied this step from an existing feature file to a new feature file**

```
   Given entity URI <Entity Resource URI>
```

**Cucumber states**
1 scenario (1 undefined)
8 steps (2 skipped, 4 undefined, 2 passed)
0m0.009s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given /^entity URI "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

P.S: I checked the directory structure of my old and new feature files and they are at the same level. Even this solution did not work for me: [Cucumber: undefined step, although step should be defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022990/cucumber-undefined-step-although-step-should-be-defined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the step matcher regex, I'd expect the step to match with double-quotes around the step:

```
Given entity URI "<Entity Resource URI>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Check with the folder structure it should be like below
Create project folder
 >Create features folder
  >Create step definitions folder
    >Save .rb files here
  >Save .feature files here.

Step definition folder and .feature files should be in the feature file.

Even i faced the same issue like you.The folder structure solved my problem.
```