# Intellij 2019.1 : undefined steps reference in feature file although test case works fine

Tags: intellij-idea, feature-selection

I am getting undefined steps reference error in one of my intellij project (using serenity BDD).

The cucumber steps are getting highlighed though but its not taking me to step definition file using Control+ click option on MAC Pro

@CucumberOptions(plugin =
        {"pretty", "html:build/cucumber", "json:build/cucumber/cucumberComponent.json", "junit:build/cucumber/cucumberComponent.xml", "com.xxx.xxx.xxxx.acceptance.test.main.SerenityCucumberForker"},
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
        glue = {"com.xx.xxx.test.stepdefinitions"})

Plugins installed:
- Cucumber for JAVA
- Gherkin

IntelliJ Version : Ultimate 2019.1

Note : 1. It works on other projects but not for this project
2. i installed uninstalled above plugins also and installed again but same result. Also, substeps plugin is uninstalled too.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And its been 2020 for a while now. Update your IDEA.

Comment: please check if this could help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102161/cucumber-undefined-step-though-defined-using-intellij/47263694#47263694

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje latest version is 2019.3

Comment: Also., i tried @MrCas but same result